# Universal Component used ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about very important thing for me. How to implement a universal component used ReactJS. For example I have a file uploader which is displayed on every page of my website (so I render it inside the main application wrapper all the time). But the problem is when I want to change some props in that uploader (add new info), I have to go through too many components when I will get the main wrapper and his function to change the props of my uploader. So it just can be unbelievable when I have to call to this uploader from ten or more places. I'm sure has to be some solution to make it simpler. 
So... Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is a challenge that comes with the react structure if your codebase becomes more complex. For this most people use Redux - and some Mobx - to create a store.

The store will hold the state instead of the parent component and it can be imported and changed from anywhere in your app.

I use Mobx, its more simple than Redux, you can find info here: https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html

The use would be something like this:

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react'
import store from './store'

const SomeComponent = observer(()=>
    <div>
        <button onClick={store.changeSomeState}>
            Toggle some text
        </button>
        {
            store.someState &&
                <p>some text</p>
        }
    </div>
);
```

observer makes it react to state changes in the store.